# Is it possible to check for correct python syntax of a given file/string from Java

Tags: java, python

I am writing a piece of code in java, part of this code deals with handling python code. I was just interested if anyone has come across a way of checking if the python code is syntactically correct during runtime. I don't actually need to run the python code, as i'm writing a program that generates small snippets of it for teaching purposes as part of a project.

Is using a system commands the only way to achieve this?

Comment: You could perhaps use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) but I'm not sure that's actually lighter than running Python instance.

Comment: I think system commands is the way to go either way since it does all the work for you. Syntax checking is heavy work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python 2, this can be done with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/):

```
new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter().compile("python code here")
```

and an exception will be thrown if it finds a problem (likely `org.python.core.PySyntaxError`)

Comment: This works well, exactly the kind of solution i was hoping exists (didn't want any depencies which couldn't be compiled into the jar), you have my thanks.

Comment: This works but sometime Jython throws syntax error for code that already works in Python.

Comment: @Neelesh is your code Python 3? Jython only supports Python 2.

Comment: No its not python 3 code. It fails in case of dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @Neelesh interesting, what was the dictionary comprehension you tried? I just tried `d = {x: y for x, y in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]}` and it didn't throw a syntax error for me. If yours works in CPython 2 but not Jython, you might also want to ask a question directly about that.

Comment: Actually i was using `2.5.3` version of `org.python.jython`. that is why getting the issue. Now changed it `org.python.jython-standalone` version `2.7.1` and it working fine.