# How to compile Python file with encoding declaration from an InputStream or bytes using Jython?

Tags: java, python, character-encoding, jython

In Java I want to check some Python 2 files for syntax errors, so using Jython seemed like a good choice. In theory this should be easy, as indicated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21080176). As I'm reading from a file, I use a `Reader`. I would really prefer to use an `InputStream`.

```java
Reader reader = openReaderToPythonFile();
new org.python.util.PythonInterpreter().compile(reader)
```

The only `compile()` options for `PythonInterpreter` take either `String` or `Reader` as parameters. This means that the content I feed it would already be in Unicode string form, not bytes.

The problem is that I want to check an existing Python file that has lines at the top indicating an encoding of UTF-8, following [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). (This is because Python 2 source files are considered ASCII by default.) It looks something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
…
```

Even if I manually read the file (correctly) as UTF-8, when I pass the string (or `Reader` instance)  to `PythonInterpreter` to compile, I get this error:

> `encoding declaration in Unicode string`

In other words `PythonInterpreter` is saying, "This file has an encoding declaration, but I can't respect the encoding declaration because you've already converted the bytes to a string before I had a chance to analyze it". But `PythonInterpreter` doesn't seem to provide a way to pass it the raw bytes or (preferably) an `InputStream`.

How can I compile a Python file with Jython if the file contains an encoding declaration? If that's not possible, as a workaround is it possible for Jython to ignore the encoding declaration and trust that I've correctly converted the bytes to a `String` or `Reader`?

Comment: Have you considered skipping the first two lines and pass the *rest* of the file content to the interpreter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that would be a last-ditch workaround, and surely there must be a workaround better than that. If I for example were to have hundreds of source files, I would have to first read and parse the source files to see if they have this header (because some of them do and some of them don't), and the header has variations according to PEP 263. But why should I need to parse the source file before handing it to Jython? The whole point of Jython is that _Jython_ is supposed to parse the source file, not me.